# How do I fix the error couldn't find packages needed when installing the gem ruby2d?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, windows-subsystem-for-linux, failed-installation, ruby2d

I have been trying to install the gem Ruby2D (https://www.ruby2d.com/learn/get-started )on my WSL Ubuntu.
But I'm getting the following error after I run gem install ruby2d:

== Ruby 2D Installation Errors =======================================

Couldn't find packages needed by Ruby 2D.
Install the following packages using `apt` and try again:

```
libsdl2-dev libsdl2-image-dev libsdl2-mixer-dev libsdl2-ttf-dev
```

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umdL7.png) .

I tried using apt-get libsdl2-dev, as suggested above but I received the error- Invalid operation.

I also tried installing the gem again after using the command apt-get install ruby-dev, but it didn't work.

It would be great if someone had any suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev
```